# Converting file values to dict (Python)

Tags: python

Help would be greatly appreciated with this as Im struggling with the final product and I need to do this without using an import function.

I need to write a function that opens and reads the file, returns a dictionary where each key is the name of a function, and the value is a list of the parameters of the function. And should return something like this.

> {"h":[x], "f":[a, b], "g":[c]}

The file I am transferring looks like this

```
def h(x):
       f(x + 4, 9)

def f(a, b):
        e = a * b
        g(e)

def g(c):
       b = 3
```

`print(c)`

`print(b)`

So far my code looks like this but I have no clue how to make it look like the final product in dictionary.

```
filename=""

ddd=dict()

new=list()


def take_name():

    global filename

    filename= input("Please, type the name of the file:")

print(take_name())



def open_read():

       global handle

       handle= open(filename, 'r')

       for line in handle:

           line=line.rstrip()

           if line.startswith('def'):

                line=line.replace('def', " ")

                line=line.replace(':', " ")


                 new.append(line)



print(new)

print(ddd)


print(open_read())
```

Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need another list but this should work for function appearing once. for repeating function it will replace the value with the latest encountered parameters

```
def open_read():

   global handle

   handle= open(filename, 'r')

   for line in handle:

       line=line.rstrip()

       if line.startswith('def'):

        line=line.replace('def', " ")
        ddd[line[0:line.index('(')].strip()]=line[line.index('(')+1:line.index(')')].split(',')
```

Comment: Do you know why it would stop at {'h': ['x']} and not go through the rest of the functions?

Comment: Nope. Have to do something with file reading. Can you print each line while printing it

Comment: My bad I got it, I put a piece of code on the wrong line. Thanks